# Enviar y Recibir Parámetros Aplicación de Consola C#

Tags: c#, nodejs, webforms

tengo una aplicación de consola que recibe parámetros mediante un WebService, una vez generado mi exe, mediante NodeJS lo invoco y le envió algunos parámetros, pero ahora necesito que mi aplicación de Consola se comunique con mi NodeJS, enviando parámetros de consola a Node.

¿Existirá alguna manera de Solucionar mi problema??
De antemano muchas gracias

Código Utilizado

Index.js

```
        var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

        var fun =function(){
           console.log("fun() start");
                exec('mi.exe', function(err, data) {
                console.log(err)
                console.log(data.toString());
            });
        }
        fun();
```

consola.cs

```
            class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {        
                int cant = args.Length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("se ha pasado el argumento: " + args[i]);
                            Console.Read();
                        }              
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar [Edge](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/), por ej:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EdgeJs;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Start()
    {
        var func = Edge.Func(@"
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
            }
        ");

        Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start().Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias... voy a revisar el código. pronto comentare mis avances!,  Saludos Cordiales, Gracias

Comment: Hola Pedro como lo implemento con mi WindowsForm, tengo desarrollada una aplicacion biometrica y me gustaria llamarla desde Node por medio de  Edge pero y las dlls del biometrico tienes alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Esto ayudará:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("node", "arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

Comment: Hola @maufkk. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por contribuir! ¿Podrías explicar brevemente cómo esto responde a la pregunta hecha, de modo que sea útil incluso para futuros lectores. Podrás encontrar el enlace a **[edit]** debajo de tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Después de Haber leído un Poco, en conseguido la forma de pasar parámetros de mi aplicación de consola a Node en tiempo Real, este es mi código espero les sirva.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Sockets;
  using System.Threading;

  namespace desktop
  {
    class Desktop
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                String data = Console.ReadLine();
                if (data.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) break; 
                SendData("127.0.0.1", 41181, data); 
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); 
            }       
         }
        public static void SendData(string host, int destPort, string data)
        {
            IPAddress dest = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];
            IPEndPoint ePoint = new IPEndPoint(dest, destPort);
            byte[] outBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data); 
            Socket mySocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp); 
            mySocket.SendTo(outBuffer, ePoint); 
            mySocket.Close(); 
        }
    }
  }
```

Aplicacion Node

```
  var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
  var fs = require('fs');

  var mySocket = 0;

  app.listen(3000);

  function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(500);
        return res.end('Error  index.html');
      }
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(data);
    });
  }

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Online');
    mySocket = socket;
  });


  var dgram = require("dgram");
  var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

  server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
    console.log("Recibiendo El Mensaje: " + msg);
    if (mySocket != 0) {
       mySocket.emit('field', "" + msg);
       mySocket.broadcast.emit('field', "" + msg);
    }
  });

  server.on("listening", function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log("Running " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
  });

  server.bind(41181);
```

y el Index.html

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <script>
                    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
                    socket.on('field', function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#field").html(data);
                    });
                </script>
                Datos Recibidos: <div id="field"></div>
            </body>
        </html>
```